# NPM Pack including .DS_Store

Tags: npm, pack

According to the docs https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files, if you put a directory in the `files` section of **package.json**, certain files inside the specified directory will be excluded no matter what - including **.DS_Store**. Additionally, files in **.gitignore** or **.npmignore** should exclude files inside any directories specified in the files section of **package.json**.

My **package.json** `files` entry is `["src", "bin"]`, yet **.DS_Store** files in **src** are still going into the tarball when I run `npm pack`. **.DS_Store** is in the **.gitignore** as well, but npm is supposed to exclude it regardless of setup.

The **README.md** file is correctly being included automatically, but I can't get **.DS_Store** to go away without explicitly including all the file extensions I want to include in the `files` section of **package.json**.

I tried NPM 6.4.1 and 6.9.0 and got the same results, am I missing something here?

Comment: Maybe only the *root* `.DS_Store` is ignored - what if you write an explicit `.npmignore`?

Comment: Had this with npm 8.0.0. Solution was to have `files` `[ "src/" ]` instead of `[ "src/**" ]` - that may be version specific. There's more discussion about the background in https://npm.community/t/ds-store-files-show-up-after-npm-publish/831

Answer (score 0):

[According to npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package),

> If there’s no **.npmignore** file, but there is a **.gitignore** file, then
>   npm will ignore the stuff matched by the **.gitignore** file. If you want
>   to include something that is excluded by your **.gitignore** file, you can
>   create an empty **.npmignore** file to override it.

I suggest you create an fresh **.npmignore** file to override your **.gitignore**. A blank **.npmignore** will ignore .DS_Store by default as you have mentioned above. npm might have some issue parsing your **.gitignore**.

Comment: This doesn't help either unfortunately. I even tried deleting both `.npmignore` and .gitignore` and got the same results.

Comment: I excluded `.DS_Store` in both `.gitignore` and `.npmignore` files but it didn't work.

Comment: `.npmignore` and `.gitignore` are both found recursively. Be sure you have only one of each file in your entire package directory. Focus on getting `.npmignore` working and use the `npm pack` command locally to troubleshoot which files are included/excluded. Publishing your package uses the same logic as `npm pack`. If you continue to have issues please post your entire package directory tree.

Comment: I have seen this issue, you will need to ensure .gitignore  is inside the folders you are including in npm bundle.   I have a 'flles' section in package.json, and for each exported folder in this list, I have a .gitignore..